# How to get the 3 items with the highest value from dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, max

Suppose I have this dictionary:

```
{"A":3,"B":4,"H":1,"K":8,"T":0}
```

I want to get the keys of the highest 3 values. So in this case I will get the keys: **`K`, `B`** and **`A`**

Comment: using `d = {"A":3,"B":4,"H":1,"K":8,"T":0}`, you can do `dict(sorted(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:3]).keys()`, prints `['A', 'K', 'B']`

Comment: Not quite a duplicate -- this question asks for the 3 (or N) largest, the other question answers getting the entire dict ordered by value. You can get the N largest more efficiently by using `heapq.nlargest` in many cases: `import heapq; heapq.nlargest(3, my_dict, key=my_dict.get)`.

Comment: Wonder if this can be extended to cover the case of `getting middle 3 items` easier?  Just curious.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can simply use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to get the keys of `dict` as:

```
my_dict = {"A":3,"B":4,"H":1,"K":8,"T":0}

my_keys = sorted(my_dict, key=my_dict.get, reverse=True)[:3]
# where `my_keys` holds the value:
#     ['K', 'B', 'A']
```

OR, you may use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) if you need value as well:

```
from collections import Counter
my_dict = {"A":3,"B":4,"H":1,"K":8,"T":0}

c = Counter(my_dict)

most_common = c.most_common(3)  # returns top 3 pairs
# where `most_common` holds the value: 
#     [('K', 8), ('B', 4), ('A', 3)]

# For getting the keys from `most_common`:
my_keys = [key for key, val in most_common]

# where `my_keys` holds the value: 
#     ['K', 'B', 'A']
```

Comment: How to get even the values? How to get result like {"K": 8, "B": 4, "A": 3} without using counter